# Algorithm help for android if statement

Tags: java, android, algorithm, if-statement

So I have used a break point but the break point never hits the if statement thats there for testing purposes

basically what I am trying to do is have a powerup load when the powerupStart == 1500; (its set to 500 for testing purposes) which it does just fine. Now I want it to go away if no collision is made within 400 and the variable being used is powerupTimeOut;  powerupTimeOut is supposed to increment once powerupStart = 1500; (or in the code below 500 for testing) but powerupTimeOut doesn't increment and I cant figure out why since its in the same place that powerupStart increments, and that works just fine.

**game code**

```
    public void update() {
        score++;
        powerupStart++;


        if (powerupStart == 500) {
        loadme();

        powerupTimeOut++;
    }
    if (powerupStart == 510) {
                   //this is where my breakpoint is for testing
                   //even without this it doesnt work
    }
    if (powerupStart > 499) {
    Log.d("powerupStart", "Powerup Start == 1000");

        powerup.setAlive(true);
        powerup.setCollidable(true);
        powerupTimeOut =0;
        powerupTimeOut++;
    }


            if (powerupTimeOut == 400) {

                powerup.setAlive(false);
                powerupTimeOut = 0;
                powerupStart = 0;

            }



    int inputs = getTouchInputs();
    if (inputs > 0) {
        touch = getTouchPoint(0);
        if (touch.y > getScreenHeight() - 50000) {
            square.position.x = touch.x - square.getWidth();
            square.position.y = touch.y - square.getHeight();
         }

       }
    } 




    //load me class
    public void loadme() {
     int w = getScreenWidth();
     int h = getScreenHeight();
     powerup = new Sprite(this);
     if (!powerup.getTexture().loadFromAsset("triangle.png")) {
         fatalError("Error loading da triangle son");
     }
     powerup.position = new Float2(10, h-10);
     powerup.setVelocity(new Float2(6.0f, -6.0f));

     //keep powerup inside secreen boundary
     Point size5 = powerup.getSize();
     powerup.addAnimation(new ReboundBehavior(new RectF
         (0 , 0 , w-size5.x, h-size5.y),size5,powerup.getVelocity()) );

         powerup.setCollidable(false);
     powerup.setIdentifier(POWERUPID);
         addToGroup(powerup);
             powerup.setAlive(false);


       }
```

Comment: That's quite confusing, buuuut: `if (powerupStart == 500) {
        loadme();
        powerupTimeOut++;
    }` <-- This means powerupTimeout will _only_ increment when powerupStart is 500, so you'll probably just end with powerupTimeOut being 1 or 2?

Comment: thats why i have it in if(powerup > 499 { powerupTimeOut++; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    powerupTimeOut =0;
    powerupTimeOut++;
```

This code sets `powerupTimeOut` to 0, then increments it by 1. You'll only ever see `powerupTimeOut` set to 1.

Remove `powerupTimeOut = 0;`.

As to your breakpoint; put something in there to break on! A `System.out.println();` won't have any negative effect on anything else, and you will trigger your break point.

Comment: ok that makes perfect sense, thank you im testing it now.

Answer (score 1):

If that's *exactly* the way your code is it's likely because the break isn't triggered because there isn't anything worth breaking for. IOW, whether it's true or false, nothing's going to happen anyway, so does it matter? This...

```
int p = 10;
if(p == 10) { // Breakpoint set on the if
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

will trigger the breakpoint. This...

```
int p = 10;
if(p == 10) { // Breakpoint set on the if
    // System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

will not in Elipse Kepler.

If there's something particularly interesting you could enable assertion checking `java -ea` and use `assert powerupStart == 510 : "Your message";`. It will break on the statement, throw an `AssertionError` if not, and report "Your message". It ends execution though so...

```
int p = 9;
assert p == 10 : "P isn't 10";
System.out.println("Hello");
```

I get the break and exception but no Hello.

Comment: so basically it wont break because its never touched?

Comment: @RichTalcik: I'm the wrong person to ask about whether it is actually "touched", it may very well get optimized out. You could look at the assembly code and see if it does. See the edit about `assert` it may be useful.